# I want to store a query as a JSON object. (Error: The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in a SELECT INTO statement.)

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #T ( DateColumn DATE, SomeColA VARCHAR (20), Temp INT, 
                  Attribute1 VARCHAR (10), Attribute2 VARCHAR (10) )
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180101', 'A', 8, 'D', NULL)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180201', 'B', 10, NULL, 'A')
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180301', 'B', 12, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180401', 'A', 14, 'D', 'C')
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180501', 'A', 15, 'E', 'Y')

SELECT DateColumn,  
       SomeColA, 
       Temp, 
       Attribute1, 
       Attribute2
-- INTO #NewTable
FROM #T FOR JSON AUTO
```

Now I've read on several pages that this is not possible. What those pages do not include however, is how this does work.

Must be quite simple, but I can't find it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what exactly you want? do you want that sql result in your c sharp json variable?

Comment: I want a new table that stores the JSON object I queried.

Comment: good question@Sql, I did not know that sqlserver will give this functionality. I added a answer with sample code to understand other user how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSON

```
SQL Server (starting with 2016)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

or upper db compatibility level to 130

Store a query as a JSON object use CTE, for example

```
;WITH x(a) as 
(
SELECT DateColumn,  
       SomeColA, 
       Temp, 
       Attribute1, 
       Attribute2
FROM #T FOR JSON AUTO
)
SELECT a INTO #b FROM x
```

Comment: Where does this say how I can store the results of my query into a new table. Sorry, but I dont see it.

Comment: Great, I tried a CTE, but slightly different syntax is needed here than usually, thanks a lot!

Comment: perfect! for a little touch, I'd use `WITH [JSON](stringify)` and `SELECT stringify FROM [JSON]`

Answer (score 2):

I just do this and it gives me json result.

```
;WITH x(a) as 
(
SELECT 
    PatientId,
    LName
FROM tblpatientmaster FOR JSON AUTO
)
--select * from x

SELECT a INTO #temp FROM x

select * from #temp
```

> [{"PatientId":1,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":2,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":5,"LName":"Kirk"},{"PatientId":6,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":7,"LName":"Dasddsa"},{"PatientId":8,"LName":"Azelia"},{"PatientId":9,"LName":"Patient"},{"PatientId":10,"LName":"Smith"},{"PatientId":11,"LName":"Brothers"},{"PatientId":12,"LName":"TtEE"},{"PatientId":13,"LName":"Tes"},{"PatientId":14,"LName":"Hernandez"},{"PatientId":15,"LName":"Velazquez"},{"PatientId":16,"LName":"Spock"},{"PatientId":17,"LName":"Patient"},{"PatientId":18,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":20,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":22,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":23,"LName":"Doe"},{"PatientId":24,"LName":"Doe"}]

Comment: Plus 1, thanks. I already accepted a similar answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

### Remove the '#' in the Name Table

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #T ( DateColumn DATE, SomeColA VARCHAR (20), Temp INT, 
              Attribute1 VARCHAR (10), Attribute2 VARCHAR (10) )
```

Live Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2d6f9/2

Output:

```
[{"DateColumn":"2018-01-01","SomeColA":"A","Temp":8,"Attribute1":"D"}, 
 {"DateColumn":"2018-02-01","SomeColA":"B","Temp":10,"Attribute2":"A"}, 
 {"DateColumn":"2018-03-01","SomeColA":"B","Temp":12},{"DateColumn":"2018-04-01","SomeColA":"A","Temp":14,"Attribute1":"D","Attribute2":"C"}, 
 {"DateColumn":"2018-05-01","SomeColA":"A","Temp":15,"Attribute1":"E","Attribute2":"Y"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I want a new table that stores the JSON object I queried.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: SELECT ... INTO #NewTable FROM #T FOR JASON AUTO runs into an error. That's what I want to solve.

Comment: Obviously, because If you want to clone this table simply you have to execute:`SELECT DateColumn,  
       SomeColA, 
       Temp, 
       Attribute1, 
       Attribute2
INTO NewTable
FROM T `